# error TS4023: Exported variable 'NotificationProvider' has or is using name 'ProviderProps' from external module ... but cannot be named

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the error I'm getting when building my Bit component library:

```
Failed task 2: "teambit.compilation/compiler:TSCompiler" of env "cannabitrx.design/tailwind/bit-preview@0.0.10"
component: cannabitrx.design/utils/notification@0.0.1
/home/daniel/Library/Caches/Bit/capsules/ec485f8a915bf25eeb84d81852287b6d7dffac6b/cannabitrx.design_utils_notification@0.0.1/utils.ts:4:9 - error TS4023: Exported variable 'NotificationProvider' has or is using name 'ProviderProps' from external module "/home/daniel/Library/Caches/Bit/capsules/ec485f8a915bf25eeb84d81852287b6d7dffac6b/node_modules/react-notification-provider/dist/index" but cannot be named.

4 const { NotificationProvider, useNotificationQueue, createMockNotificationQueue } =          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is my code:

```js
import { createNotificationContext } from "react-notification-provider";
import { NotificationProps } from "@cannabitrx/ui.notification";

const { NotificationProvider, useNotificationQueue, createMockNotificationQueue } =
  createNotificationContext<NotificationProps>();

export { NotificationProvider, useNotificationQueue, createMockNotificationQueue };
```

It works during development and testing, but not during builds. I'm not sure why.

I've looked up this error online and found related problems, but I haven't found a solution to get this to work.

I suspect it may be because the declaration file for the [`react-notification-provider`](https://github.com/anthonyshort/react-notification-provider) library doesn't export `ProviderProps`:

```js
interface ProviderProps<Notification> {
    queue?: ImmutableQueue<Notification>;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

I opened an issue on GitHub for this, but they look fairly inactive, so I can't wait for a fix (and I don't want to fork their repo just for this).

Does anyone know how to fix this, or if there's a workaround? Thanks in advance.